# Create Photo_Album

Tags: iphone, photo

I want to create a photo album in iphone programatically.Is there any way to handle or store the images in oe album
 Any suggestions?

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible with the official SDK,

Check [here](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/34719-create-photo-album-programmatically.html)

here from apple developer community

[Creating Photo Albums on iPhone](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1413776?start=0&tstart=0)

Comment: He wants to create a **Photo Album** not a Photo Gallery.

Comment: Yes Wright, the problem is i want to take the pic from camera as well as photogallery  and store in one album with same userid.Afterthat we can share that album on facebook and also at twitter

Answer (score 3):

There is an ALAssetsLibrary method for creating albums (since iOS 5.0):

```
ALAssetsLibrary* library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[library addAssetsGroupAlbumWithName:@"my pics" resultBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group) {
    NSLog(@"adding album:'my pics', success: %s", group.editable ? "yes" : "no");
} failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"error adding album");
}];
```

This creates a folder at the top level of "Albums" in the photos App alongside the Camera Roll.

Answer (score 0):

Without being jailbroken, no. You will need to create them in iPhone or iTunes.

If you are jailbroken, theres a tweak on Cydia.

Programmatically, no.